# Clean code question: EF Core parametrize which properties to include

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

This question is about clean code and best practices. We are using **.NET Core 3.1** to develop a web application. Let's say we have `PostsController` which accepts requests, `PostService` which returns some data from the database and `Post` database model with some properties.

```
public class PostsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IPostsService _postsService;

    public PostsController(IPostsService postsService)
    {
        _postsService = postsService;
    }

    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        Post post = _postsService.Get(id);
        return View(post);
    }
}

public class PostsService : IPostsService
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;

    public PostsService(MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public Post Get(int id)
    {
        return _dbContext.Post
            .Include(x => x.FirstPropery)
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}
```

Everything fine, right? But let's say that there is another controller (or another service, doesn't really matter) which also calls `_postsService.Get(id)` but it doesn't need `Post` with just `FirstProperty`. It also needs its `SecondPropery`. So appropriate service function for it would be:

```
public Post Get(int id)
{
    return _dbContext.Post
        .Include(x => x.FirstPropery)
        .Include(x => x.SecondPropery)
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

Imagine that there could be `n` controllers all needing Post by its `Id`, but each needing its own included properties.

What should we do in this case?

1. Create `n` different service methods, each of them returning post with different included properties? Ugly.
2. Create a general service method which includes `ALL` properties? Ugly, slow, many properties are not needed.
3. ... ?

Is there a way to parametrize which `Include`s you need? I don't want to hardcode any string properties since it can lead to many errors. I need a clean solution which would produce compile time error if we change a name of some property in `Post` model.

Answer (score 1):

> Imagine that there could be n controllers all needing Post by its Id, but each needing its own included properties.

This is why your controllers should have access to an `IQueryable<Post>`.  That's the type that allows the controller to specify the query.  The alternative you are suggesting is just a very limited, home-grown API to give the controller control over the query.